# How to create an OntModel for an ontology which imports another ontology?

Tags: jena, ontology

I have an ontology that imports another ontology (both are stored in the same folder on my machine, created using Protege & saved as RDF/XML). When I create the ontology model in my java application through Jena, I get the following

```
0 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment  - Failed to find configuration: location-mapping.ttl;location-mapping.rdf;location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.rdf;etc/location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.ttl
297 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
300 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.LocationMapper  - Failed to find configuration: file:location-mapping.rdf;file:location-mapping.n3;file:location-mapping.ttl;file:etc/location-mapping.rdf;file:etc/location-mapping.n3;file:etc/location-mapping.ttl
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorURL
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorURL
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
301 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Found: file:ont-policy.rdf (ClassLoaderLocator)
1002 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - readModel(model,http://www.semanticweb.org/myOnt)
1002 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - readModel(model,http://www.semanticweb.org/myOnt, null)
1002 [main] DEBUG com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager  - Not mapped: http://www.semanticweb.org/myOnt
2065 [main] WARN com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager  - An error occurred while attempting to read from http://www.semanticweb.org/myOnt. Msg was 'http://www.semanticweb.org/myOnt'.
```

This exception is also thrown

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.DoesNotExistException
```

I understand that it is unable to find the imported ontology, and that one solution might be to create separate models for both ontologies, but there's an objective property in parent ontology which relates one of its class to the classes of imported ontology.

What can I do?

Comment: You could disable the automatic loading of imported ontologies. See [setDynamicImports()](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#setDynamicImports-boolean-).

Comment: Just did that...still getting the same messages :(.

Comment: Without seeing any or your code or your data, I don't know how much anyone is going to be able to help you.  What's the code you're using to load the ontology?

Comment: If it's the same message, it is still trying to load URL http://www.semanticweb.org/myOnt. If you visit that link in a browser, you'll see it is 404.

Comment: Yes Joshua, I should have posted the code as well..my bad.

Both Joshua & Andy, thank you very much for your suggestions. I really appreciate it. :) 

I have just resolved the issues. For the exception, I gave it an alternate path on my system. As for the messages, it turns out I had to create a union of two models for both ontologies, in which I read the files separately. It was not reading with URI, (I still don't know why?!), so I used the InputStream one instead. Now it is getting classes from both ontologies through my OntModel.